# how to write a cross tuple query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

How can i write a cross tuple query that will select from two tables in the same database and the output will have repeating columns with different data.
This is my attended query:

```
    SELECT results.AcademicYear,results.Semester,student.name,results.StudentNo,results.CourseNo,results.CAMarks,results.ExamMarks,results.TotalMarks,results.Grade
FROM results,student
WHERE results.StudentNo IN(
    SELECT student.studentNO
    FROM student
    )
GROUP BY AcademicYear, Semester,name
ORDER BY name,AcademicYear ASC,Semester ASC
```

This image is an example of a desired output of the query:
[image: This image is an example of a desired output of the query]

Comment: Please show any of your attempts at writing your own cross tuple query.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're after but...`Select * from A Cross join B?`  or maybe you just need a self join on the table...

Answer (score 0):

If there are many courses for same student in same semester, the column count will increase greatly. The following solution handle up to 2 courses in same semester for same student.

```
SELECT 
    results.AcademicYear,results.Semester,student.name,results.StudentNo,
    results.CourseNo,results.CAMarks,results.ExamMarks,results.TotalMarks,results.Grade
FROM results 
        LEFT JOIN results r2 ON results.AcademicYear = r2.AcademicYear AND  
                                results.Semester = r2.Semester AND
                                results.name = r2.name AND
                                results.CourseNo != r2.CourseNo
        INNER JOIN student ON results.StudentID = student.StudentID
ORDER BY name,AcademicYear ASC,Semester ASC
```